Ubuntu Studio 24.04.1 LTS doesn't show UbuntuStudio Pipewire Audio Control Panel. Cannot to Configure It
I use Ubuntu Studio and I upgraded from 22.04.4 LTS to 24.04.1 LTS (standard upgrading procedure, not errors, not problems at all).
It seems to work fine, but... It seems like Pipewire isn't complete activated or installed.
Even the fact that I can see all the Pipewire components as installed (Synaptic), I cannot to configure it because I cannot to see the new "Quantum" control panel. Where is it?
Also, even the fact I get sound from Jack and PulseAudio, I cannot to use more than one audio apps (let's say: MuseScore and Qtractor) at the same time, because the sound is stuttering, from one or both apps. It wasn't this way before the upgrading.
Also, almost all audio apps are connected directly to the default analog audio out and, at the same time, to the Jack Mixer and Calf Effects plugin, whatever configuration I made in the qjackctl or qwgraph apps, producing an annoying double sound.
In other words, it is evident there is something wrong here.
How can I fix it? Is there some automatic way to fix this? ???
Is there a way to test if the all the Pipewire packages are fine installed and activated?
And, if it's not, How to fix it? ???

I think I got to fix it: I just remove all pipewire and pulseaudio packages installation and I reinstall all again. Now, it seems to be fine. I hope so!!!
